# Making HTTP(s) requests between two App Engine projects

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Does making HTTP(s) requests from an App Engine project to another App Engine project (on the same account) also count towards the bandwidth quota (Incoming and/or Outgoing)?

My question is actually simple but I can't seem to find any information about it in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An outgoing request, even if is from one project you own to another, is an outgoing request, so yes, [it would count towards your quota](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Requests).

If possible, as a [piece of advice](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine#app_engine_services_as_microservices), try to convert what you have in those projects into services of only one project.

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting the same.